# tKinter window not showing opencv footage

Tags: python, opencv, video, tkinter, usb

I'm having a problem where if i have my webcam connected from the beginning, My program executes as expected however, if i dont have the webcam plugged in, and plug it in after the program has started. it makes a tKinter window of the right size, but, it does not show the webcam footage like it is suppose to.

Heres some code:

```
from tkinter import *  # Import the tkinter module (For the Graphical User Interface)
import cv2  # Import the cv2 module for web camera footage
import PIL  # Import the pillow library for image configuration.
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  # Import the specifics for Image configuration.

print("[INFO] Imports done")

width, height = 800, 600  # Define The width and height widget for cap adjustment
RootGeometry = str(width) + "x" + str(height)  # Make a variable to adjust tkinter frame
print("[INFO] Geometries made")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height)
print("[INFO] Cap set")

root = Tk()
print("[INFO] Window made")

root.title("Main Window")
root.configure(background="white")
root.geometry(RootGeometry)
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
lmain = Label(root)
lmain.pack()
print("[INFO] Configuration of cap done.")


def ShowFrame(frame):
    print("[INFO] Show frame Initialized.")
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = PIL.Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    print("[INFO] After 10 initializing")
    lmain.after(10, CheckSource)
    print("[INFO] Showed image")


def CheckSource():
    print("[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.")
    ok, frame = cap.read()
    if ok:
        print("[INFO] [DEBUG] if Ok initialized")
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            print("[WARNING] Exiting app after command")

        ShowFrame(frame)

    else:
        print("[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.")
        lmain.after(10, CheckSource)


CheckSource()
root.mainloop()
```

something to note is that the webcamera never gets detected. Because my output is allways this no matter if i plug in the camera or not:

```
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.

Somewhere here i connected the camera. 
But the camera is never detected.

[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
[INFO] CheckSource Triggered.
[WARNING] No source found. Looking for source.
```

Comment: Camera detection happens during the call to `cv2.VideoCapture`. You only call that once, in the beginning. Plugging the camera in afterwards is rather futile in that case.

Comment: so you're saying that i should call cv2.VideoCapture(0) instead of ok, frame  = cap.read @DanMašek ? [EDIT] and also, i could make a def of config cap using the statement requirement of cap from my CheckSource function?

Comment: you can use [isOpened()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a9d2ca36789e7fcfe7a7be3b328038585) to check if the camera is know to the program. If true, read the frame, if not, retry to detect the cam with `cv2.VideoCapture`.

Comment: now the problem is. It takes way too much time to VideoCapture and now makes a wierd behavior where it shows one frame every 2 - 3 seconds